# How to import function from lib.es6.d

Tags: typescript

I want to import the `all` function from `lib.es6.d`, so that I can write:

```
        await all([
            promise1,
            promise2
        ]);
```

. . instead of `await Promise.all`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `all` method of the Promise object to the Promise context and create a new variable `all` like below.

```
const all = Promise.all.bind(Promise);
```

Now, you'll be able to use the `all` in the way that you want.

```
await all([promise1, promise2]);
```

Create a module which exports the `all` variable and you'll be able to use it everywhere by importing it.